React Tailwind Muliple Headless UI Dropdown Menus(Typescript)
I am using mulitple Headless UI dropdown menus. So when one of the dropdown is in open state and I try to click on the another dropdown menu, it just closes the current dropdown alone and doesn't open the new dropdown. So every time I have to click twice when switching between dropdowns.
Is there any way I can switch between drop downs in single click on the new drop down

You can use modal={false} on the dropdown. This prevents the scroll lock and that way you only have to click once.
example:    <MenuItems modal={false} /> 

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
